# Using WebSphere clustering for load balancing

Tags: ejb, websphere, cluster-computing, load-balancing

I have two tier system.
WebSphere Application Server.

The first tier is called "Web" but is a regular ApplicationServer Cluster.
The second tier is called "App" and is a regular ApplicationServer Cluster.

I invoke some EJBs using rmi:iiop:
but the distribution of requests in the App isn't even.

I would like to have the effect of a load balancer.

Is that possible?
By the way, I don't have weights (other than default == 2), so I don't understand why a certain App server is given most of the requests.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the members of the "App" cluster running on the same nodes as the members of the "Web" cluster?

Comment: No. each server has its own node/host.

Comment: So the distribution across the "web" cluster does seem evenly split, but that across the "app" cluster does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a very nice presentation about this issue:

[Workload Management (WLM) Overview and Problem Determination](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27012101&aid=1)

What  you see is probably due to "Prefer Local" which sends the request to the server resides on the same hostname.

Usually its a good idea but you can turn it off of course.

Comment: The user said that each server is running on its own node/host. Therefore prefer local is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Yes I wrote that before still the presentation explain how to investigate the issue